# upload 2 files to google drive and python

Tags: python, google-apps-script

I wont upload 2 file to google drive with python and google script (not API)
I would also like to send the name of the file

I got this answer to my first question

```
You can do this by publishing a web app to run as "Me"(you) with access: "Anyone, even anonymous".


Server side:
function doPost(e){
  const FOLDER_ID = '###FOLDER_ID###';
  var name = e.parameter.name;
  saveFile(e.postData.contents,name,FOLDER_ID);
  return 'Success';
}

function saveFile(data,name,id) { 
    data = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64DecodeWebSafe(data));
    DriveApp.getFolderById(id)
    .createFile(data.setName(name))
}
Client side:
import requests, base64
url = '###WEB_APP_PUBLISHED_URL###'
name = '###FILENAME###'
requests.post(url+'?name='+name,data=base64.urlsafe_b64encode(open('##UPLOAD FILE PATH##','rb').read()))
```

This answer helps me send one file without its name

I saw you could do it that way

But I did not understand what I was changing on the server side

```
files = {'file': ('report.xls', open('report.xls', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}
```

What I need to change on the server side to get the file?

thanks

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can I ask you about ``I wont upload 2 file to google drive with python``? Do you want to upload 2 files by running the python script? 2. What is the script below ``I was changing on the server side``?

Comment: I see that you are sending the name as a parameter in the URL, so i don't understand the problem. Can you explain the problem you're facing with more details?